# undefined - annoying JavaScript bug

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and cannot understand why I am getting an 'undefined' before my object properties are listed..? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

As you can tell I am a newbie to JavaScript, any help is majorly appreciated!

```js
let player_profile;

const players = [
    {
        name: "George Ford",
        age: 22,
        position: "Back" 
    },
    {
        name: "Ben Youngs",
        age: 28,
        position: "Forward" 
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  player_profile += '<h2>Name: ' + players[i].name + '</h2>';
  player_profile += '<p>Age: ' + players[i].age + '</p>';
}

document.write(player_profile);
```

Comment: You don't initialize `player_profile`, so in the first `+=` its value is `undefined`.

Comment: `player_profile` is undefined when you first concatenate to it. You need to initialize it to an empty string.

Comment: You need to initialize `player_profile`: `let player_profile = "";`

Answer (score 2):

`let player_profile;` declares the variable and (implicitly) gives it an initial value of `undefined`.

`player_profile += some_string` then appends a string to it. This converts `undefined` to a string, the result of which is `"undefined"`.

If you want the initial value to be an empty string, then say so explicitly:

```
let player_profile = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you've not initialized your player_profile:

```
let player_profile = "";

const players = [
    {
        name: "George Ford",
        age: 22,
        position: "Back" 
    },
    {
        name: "Ben Youngs",
        age: 28,
        position: "Forward" 
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  player_profile += '<h2>Name: ' + players[i].name + '</h2>';
  player_profile += '<p>Age: ' + players[i].age + '</p>';
}

document.write(player_profile);
```